# Feedback needed

Tags: feedback, sound-design

Hey guys!

I hate to spam with more videos with feedback required. But i need your help.

I want to apply to do a placement in the summer or possibly even a year long placement (either in UK or USA, although i would preffer USA).

I've been putting together some stuff. I just finished a clip of a video that i want to use as a part of my prtfolio. The whole finished version is a clip around 5min. I've never contacted any companies before so i'm a little bit worried and i don't really know what to expect.

Let me know what you think. Any criticism is more than welcome (as long as it's constructive ;)

clip: http://vimeo.com/20109475

rest of my stuff if you have some time to kill: http://harmonoize.wordpress.com/about/

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short on time - I may revist this in a bit - heres my 4 liner critique:

It is really LOUD. I mean REALLY LOUD. Check your reference signal and monitoring levels before mixing. You have a lot of high end spectrum sitting in this.

Id like to hear more organic detail on the dog - record a dog for it, less reverb or room sound on its chomping maybe. Its a bit sharp.

The footsteps sound weird at the end.

Overall it feels really surreal and matches the mood of the picture. It sounds very artsy in a way. Sometimes I feel like its a bit too synthetic at times... but it is the Animatrix so its whatevs.

Cool things.

Comment: @C3Sound -> thanks for the fast reply! It was just a quick bounce to get some feedback. I will keep the dynamic range in mind when i sit down to the final mix. The dog is actually me chewing gum, a little bit processed as the dog is being 'eaten' by that 'glitch' thing. The end where the girl runs? There is hardly anything done to those last few seconds. 
Yah, being Animatrix, i kinda wanted to go for a synthetic/surreal feal, it gets a little bit more organic later on in the clip, but that part is not yet finished. I have a plan to redesign the sound for LOTR to show more of the organic side.

Answer (score 0):

Any more feedback? Some other people?

Answer (score 0):

I really liked it S_Mich. My only suggestion is to add some footsteps at the beginning and middle of the video (this is truly personal opinion though). I have to agree with C3Sound about the levels that are very loud, and the footsteps at the end are weird (maybe check the reverb?)

Comment: @Nikos -> thanks! there actually are footsteps in there, they just die-out in the mix.
i'm going to sit down to it again this week and move the vid forward.

thanks a lot for you input!